# how to use zoom.wheelDelta in d3 v4

Tags: d3.js

I do not know why wheelDelta not working . it says wheeldelta is not a function. I want to control zooming level on scroll up and down of mouse wheel. if I can defined delta value then I can define how much zoom will happen on a single tick rotation of scroll. the default behavior is too fast. I am using this reference
https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/blob/master/README.md#_zoom

```
 svg = d3.select("#treeSection").append("svg")
                   .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
                   .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                   .call(d3.zoom()
                       .wheelDelta([2])
                       .scaleExtent([1 / 2, 4])
                       .on("zoom", zoomed));


               g = svg.append("g")
                   .attr("transform", "translate(" +
                       margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");






           function zoomed() {
               g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
           }
```

Comment: You have to specify a function, not an array.

Comment: but documenation says it just need a delta value for e.g. as i used scaleExtent       https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/blob/master/README.md#_zoom

Comment: It says *"If delta is specified, sets the wheel delta function to the specified **function**"*.

Comment: I tried this and not working. I do not know if its a right way.                                              
               .call(d3.zoom()
                   .wheelDelta(wheelDelta)
                   .scaleExtent([1 / 2, 4])
                   .on("zoom", zoomed));

         
      function wheelDelta() {
  return -d3.event.deltaY * (d3.event.deltaMode ? 120 : 1) / 500;
}
       

       function zoomed() {
           g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
       }

Comment: it started to work for me with the current version of https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js (uploaded on 2017-07-14)

Comment: @ThomasRebele could you please post code sample how did you called you function  and whats inside your delta function.

Comment: the issue was the version of D3 I was using. I was using 4.2.0 . i changed it to 4.10.0 and its working. thanks everyone for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the `wheelDelta` function
Make a wheel delta function

```
function myDelta() {
  return -d3.event.deltaY * (d3.event.deltaMode ? 120 : 1) / 1500;
}
```

You may increase the constant 1500 to any number of your choice for regulating the delta.

Now in zoom define the wheelDelta like this:

```
var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 32])
    .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .wheelDelta(myDelta)//your function
    .on("zoom", zoomed);
```

Reference [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/blob/master/README.md#zoom_wheelDelta)

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/l0uRNn5ja6UxdvVoTXjD?p=preview)

Comment: thanks bro. the problem with my code was that vesion of D3 was 4.2.0 and the version you used is 4.10.0. Now its working fine.I changed my D3 version to 4.10.0